# Django admin - dynamically update through ajax choices of a ChoiceField in ModelForm

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms, django-widget

I'm working with a ModelForm in the admin. I have two ChoiceFields which are populated with choices in `__init__`:

```
self.fields['city'] = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False,
    )
self.fields['city'].choices=get_cities_tuple(region_code=region_code)
self.fields['city'].initial = my_initial_city_value

self.fields['zip'] = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False,
    )
self.fields['zip'].choices=get_cities_tuple(region_code=region_code, city_name=city_name)
self.fields['zip'].initial = my_initial_zip_value
```

now the options of those html select rendered are dynamically updated through ajax functions. 
The problem is that while saving, the selected options is recognized as not valid cause is not in the initial choices:

```
Select a valid choice. <my_choice> is not one of the available choices.
```

Any idea on how to solve it?

Maybe subclassing the original ChoiceField or the Select widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved populating those ChoiceField in `__init__` with all choiches available, and the populating only the widget choices:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    self.fields['city'] = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False,
    choices=get_all_cities_tuple()
    )   
    self.fields['zip'] = forms.ChoiceField(
    required=False,
    choices=get_all_zips_tuple()
    )

self.fields['city'].widget.choices=get_cities_tuple(region_code=region_code)
self.fields['city'].initial = my_initial_city_value 
self.fields['zip'].widget.choices=get_zips_tuple(
                                          region_code=region_code,
                                          city_name=city_name
                                      )
self.fields['zip'].initial = my_initial_zip_value
```

While this is not the best approach in term of computational cost, that's what have worked for me for this specific task.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out this solution

It worked for me  refer and [Old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19569344/3017644)

Comment: The link helped me. The link is to Stackoverflow. Does Stackoverflow change its links? The answer provided by the link is really short. Including the essential parts would involve copying the whole answer. Then issues of plagiarism would come up.