# Dynamic select options not validating Django

Tags: django, django-forms, choicefield

I have a model Foo. I have a modelform FooForm. In FooForm I am adding a dynamic field "too". This is a select field.

```
 FooForm(modelform)
    too = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select())
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
```

In the template I am adding options dynamically to this "too field"

```
$('.too').append('<option value='timepass'>'+timepass'</option>');
```

In the view these values are not validating, as there are no choices available to it for comparing. How do I validate and extract this field ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using a `forms.ChoiceField` you must use `forms.CharField`, with `widget=forms.Select()`, this way you are open to any value and not limited by a choices list in the form